# JPA @Column to prevent empty values

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, string

Is there an argument for `@Column` to prevent an empty String value ? Empty values are being a problem inside JLists. If not, what concise logic is the norm to be added to the entity to avoid this.

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String roleName;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [Java Bean Validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html#gkcrg). These annotations will help you:

- `@Pattern` - define a regular expression to detect empty values
- `@Size` - check the size of the String.

Comment: Bean validation is very handy and dropping the hibernate validation jar was sufficient to use the `@Size` annotation. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can use @Size annotation like this:

```
@Size(min=1)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private String roleName;
```